# SML more or less large systems: compilers and interpreters interoperability

Tags: sml

This is about programming in the large with SML. First a summary of what's seems to be available for that purpose, then a tiny summary, then finally, the simple question.

### The `use` pseudo‑clause

[Top-level type, exception, and value identifiers (standardml.org)](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/top-level-chapter.html#section:2)

> Note that the use function is special. Although 
>   not defined precisely, its intended purpose is 
>   to take the pathname of a file and treat the 
>   contents of the file as SML source code typed
>   in by the user. It can be used as a simple build 
>   mechanism, especially for interactive sessions. 
>   Most implementations will provide a more sophisticated 
>   build mechanism for larger collections of source 
>   files. Implementations are not required to supply 
>   a use function.

Then later

```
val use : string -> unit    (* implementation dependent *)
```

Its drawbacks are: not supported by MLton at least, and while not standardized, seems to have the same behaviour with all major SML systems, which is to reload a unit as many times as a `use` is encountered for it, which is not OK due to the generative semantic of SML (defining a structure multiple times, will result into as much different definitions, which is especially wrong with types definitions).

### ML Basis Files

There exist so called “ML Basis Files”: [MLBasis (mlton.org)](http://mlton.org/MLBasis) and [ML‑Kit ML Basis Files (sourceforge.net)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mlkit/index.php?title=ML_Basis_Files).

### The `load` pseudo‑clause

MoscowML has `load` which acts like `use` which uses only once, i.e. does not reload a unit if it's already loaded, which is what's expected to compose a system.

### Summary

- `load` is nice, but only recognized by MoscowML
- MLBasis Files may be nice, but it's not recognized by neither Poly/ML nor Moscow ML
- MLton does not recognize `use`

Putting everything in a single big bundle file, is the only one interoperable thing working with all compilers and interpreters; that works, but that quickly become a burden.

### The question

Is there a known interoperable way to compose a system made of multiple SML source files?

Answer (score 4):

One system you did not mention is SML/NJ's Compilation Manager (CM), which is quite powerful. And there are a few other, less known systems.

But that notwithstanding, the situation is indeed dire. There simply is no standardised separate compilation mechanism for SML. In practice that means that writing portable Makefiles or something alike is rather painful.

For [HaMLet](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/hamlet/) I went through that pain, in order to make it compile with 7 different SML implementations. The approach is to use a restricted (dependency-ordered) CM file and the necessary amount of make + sed hackery to generate meta files for other systems from that. It can also generate a file containing respective 'use' invocations for all the sources, for all other systems that at least support that. All in all it's not pretty, but works sufficiently well.